# Custom Authentication on WCF VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf

I'm trying to implement a little WCF for my University project but, when implementing CustomUserNamePassword Auth on the WCF it crashes with the following error: 
[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'CoreWS.CoreAuthWs' from assembly 'CoreWS'.

```
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="CoreWS.CoreAuthWs,CoreWS" />
      </serviceCredentials>
```

Whats wrong??? Any Issues on the Web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following things :

- The class should be public (and you could set a breakpoint inside)
- It should have a public default constructor
- Of course, check assembly and namespace name - you probably know that VB.Net compiler puts the class in an implicit namespace that is the project name

Good luck

Comment: Carlos, did it help ?